# Erro ao Executar Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, migrations

Amigos, tenho duas entidades DeliveryFee e City, onde DeliveryFee tem uma FK de City, quando eu fui retirar o relacionamento entre as duas e gerei o Migration ele me retornou o seguinte erro.

> objeto 'FK_dbo.DeliveryFees_dbo.Cities_Cities_Id' depende de coluna 'CityId'.
>   Falha em ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN CityId porque um ou mais objetos acessam esta coluna.

segue o Código do arquivo gerado de migração.

```
public partial class Remove_City_DeliveryFee : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.DeliveryFees", "CityId", "dbo.Cities");
        DropIndex("dbo.DeliveryFees", new[] { "CityId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.DeliveryFees", "CityId");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.DeliveryFees", "CityId", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.DeliveryFees", "CityId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.DeliveryFees", "CityId", "dbo.Cities", "Id");
    }
}
```

e minhas classes.

```
public class DeliveryFee : BaseModel
{
    public float Distance { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    //public long CityId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long BranchId { get; set; }

    //public virtual City Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

public class City : BaseModel
{
    public City()
    {
        ZipCodes = new HashSet<Neighborhood>();
        //DeliveryFees = new HashSet<DeliveryFee>();
    }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("State")]
    public long StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Neighborhood> ZipCodes { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<DeliveryFee> DeliveryFees { get; set; }

}
```

o Entity reclama que tem um relacionamento a mais com  CityId que estou removendo mas não tenho.

Comment: As duas tabelas estão vazias?

Comment: somente a City esta populada

Comment: Ele não esta conseguindo dropar a FK que faz a relação com CityId e quando chega na hora de dropar a coluna, acontece um erro de integridade que a FK precisa. Não sei te dizer sem ser o fato de ainda existir registro entre os dois se relacionando.

Comment: apaguei ate os registros de City pra ver se dava certo mas nada o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a Solução encontrada foi voltar a migração para o ponto anterior ao do relacionamento, no meu caso deu certo pois a migração anterior foi a de vinculação das tabelas segue o comando

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:201710021159389_Type_Delivery_Seeds_Raname_Restaurant_id -Verbose
```

Valeu a todos.